# How can I pass a variable in mvc method used in jQuery code to call partial view?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a dropdown control in my view and if user select a option in dropdown button then I have to pass it to my jQuery code and pass to MVC method which is use in jQuery code to call partial view. I have attached my code image.[image]
this is my working code

```
    @{
    ViewBag.Title = "CreateBidSecondStep";
}

<div id="container">
    <div class="wrapper white-bg">
        <div class="row mar-xsm-b">
            <div class="col s12 l12 m12">
                <div class="step">
                    <span class="pull-left">Step 1 &gt;</span>
                    <span class="active pull-left">Step 2 &gt;</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <div class="row mar-sm-b">
            <div class="col s12 m12 l12">
                <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
                    <div class="border-light">
                        <div class="heading24 mar-sm-l mar-sm-r">Bill of Material</div>
                        <div class="row">

                            <div class="col s8 m8 l8" id="billMaterial">
                                <div class="ProdHeading">Search</div>
                                <div class="pull-left">
                                    <label class="label pull-left">Item Code</label>
                                    <select class="browser-default pull-left width_120" name="itemcode" id="itemcode" enable>
                                        <option>Item Code</option>
                                        <option>Item Code</option>
                                        <option>Item Code</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                                <div class="pull-left mar-lg-l">
                                    <label class="label pull-left">Item Name</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="pull-left" name="cap" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="pull-left mar-lg-l">
                                    <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" name="action" id="btnsearch">Search</button>
                                </div>
                                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                <div class="bdr-gray-b mar-sm-t mar-sm-b"></div>
                                <div class="pull-left">
                                    <label class="label pull-left width_120">Total Item Quantity</label>
                                    <input type="number" maxlength="5" class="pull-left width_80" name="cap" />
                                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                    <label class="label pull-left width_120">Item Quantity</label>
                                    <input type="number" class="pull-left width_80" name="cap" />
                                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                    <label class="label pull-left width_120">Location</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="pull-left width_80" name="cap" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="pull-left mar-lg-l">
                                    <label>Description</label>
                                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                    <textarea></textarea>
                                </div>
                                <div class="pull-left mar-lg-l mar-md-t">
                                    <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" style="bottom:0px" type="submit" name="action">Add to BOM</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col s4 m4 l4">
                                <div class="table_h2" id="SAPdiv">

                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col s12 l12 m12 ">
                                <div class="table_h2">
                                    <table class="TableID2">
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th>Item Code</th>
                                                <th>Description</th>
                                                <th>Quantity</th>
                                                <th>Approved Supplied</th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row border-light mar-sm-t pad-sm">
                        <div class="col s12 l12 m12">
                            <div class="pull-left">
                            </div>
                            <div class="pull-right">
                                <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" name="action">PREVIOUS</button>
                                <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" name="action">SEND TO ADVANCE PURCHASE</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src=" ~/Scripts/JobManager/BiddingSecondStepPartial.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {

        $('#btnsearch').click(function (data) {
            var itemcode = $('#itemcode').value;
                $.post("@Url.Action("SAPPartailView", "CreateBid")", function(data) {
                    if (data) {
                        $('#SAPdiv').append(data);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</div>
```

Comment: Please post your code as text.

Comment: Also, `.value` will return an error on jQuery object.

Comment: Need to understand you are trying to mix 2 languages that run in 2 different environments at different times. You can't pass `itemcode` to your server code because it's not even a server side variable and won't be avaialble either until the actual event occurs in browser long after all the server code is finsihed

Comment: ok then how can we get a value from html code to jquery code if it is html control for dropdown.User select a option in html dropdown then click a button.how can we detect the value of dropdown in jquery code

Comment: You are mixing server-side with client side code!

Comment: ok then can you tell me how can i call a partial view by my jquery code....actually i search for it and get that solution.and it is working but i need also to pass a variable from my html to partial view...can you give me a solution

Comment: please give me solution ,do not tell me my errors...i just told what i want to do.if you have solution then comment.

Answer (score 1):

Try This one

```
$(function () {
    $('#btnsearch').click(function (data) {
        var itemcode = $('#itemcode').value;
            $.post("/SAPPartailView/CreateBid", { itemcode : itemcode }, function(data) {
                if (data) {
                    $('#SAPdiv').append(data);
                }
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i just got a solution ....thanks for giving your efforts.

this is the way by which i can call a partial view from my jquery code passing with a parameter..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var url = '@Url.Action("SAPPartailView", "CreateBid")';
        $('#btnsearch').click(function () {
            var keyWord = $('#itemcodeid').val();
            $('#SAPdiv').load(url, { searchText: keyWord });
        })
```

and in partial view i have to take parameter like..

```
public PartialViewResult SAPPartailView(string searchText)
        {
            return PartialView("_CreateBidSecondStepSAP",newlist);
        }
```

this is working solution